# Using spread syntax to dynamically merge objects

Tags: javascript

The new [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)   can be used to elegantly merge several objects in the following way:

```
const person = { name: 'David Walsh', gender: 'Male' };
const tools = { computer: 'Mac', editor: 'Atom' };

const summary = {...person, ...tools};
```

Is there a way to use this in a dynamical scenario, where the number and names of the objects to be merged are not known beforehand?

If

```
var objects_to_be_merged = get_objects();
```

generated an iterable list of objects during runtime, how can I use the spread operator iteratively to create a summary object like in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` with spread syntax to merge array of objects.

```js
const person = { name: 'David Walsh', gender: 'Male' };
const tools = { computer: 'Mac', editor: 'Atom' };

const objects = () => [person, tools];
const summary = Object.assign({}, ...objects());
console.log(summary)
```

Comment: Worth noting that `{ ...[] }` results in `{}`

Comment: Also, `{ ...{} }` results in `{}`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use this in a dynamical scenario, where the number and names of the objects to be merged are not known beforehand?

Not with property spread notation*, no. Instead, you'd use `Object.assign`. If the number of objects is unknown, you'd pass it an array using (amusingly) array spread:

```
const combined = Object.assign({}, ...get_objects());
```

(Presumably `get_objects()` returns an array or other iterable.)

---

* property spread is [a Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) at the moment, but it's supported without a runtime flag in current Chrome and Firefox and likely to be in ES2018. (Whereas *array* spread was in ES2015.)